# How to phrase "first semester in college"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to say that I just completed my very first semester in college, but I'm not sure of the most natural way to phrase it.
Here's my attempt:
最近、大学には最初の学期がもう終わりました。

Comment: 「大学には」を「大学では」に変えれば、他はそのままでも良いかと…

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

> 大学で最初の学期が終わった`ところ`です。

or

> 大学で最初の学期が終わった`ばかり`です。

If the listener knows anything about you, then you would probably not need to clarify that the semester was a semester of college.

If you use `ところ` it feels like you are in the context of a timeline. Like past events have already been discussed, `ところ` zooms into right now. I don't think context is needed for `ばかり`.

I'm not a native speaker, but no one has offered an answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use 学期 along with their numeral, i.e. 1学期, 2学期 and (sometimes) 3学期. Using 一, 二 and 三 is also fine.

I'd go for a somehow simpler

> 大学の最初の1学期がもう終わった。

Even though 最初の1学期 seems redundant, it's easier to catch than 最初の学期.